# Entity Framework 6 related entity where datetime clause doesn't translate to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How do I get the date filter into the generated SQL query without access to database context?

EF makes some very expensive queries. I don't cast or use the results as IEnumerable, so I would expect EF to make an efficient query. I would expect it to use the start and stop times to filter the results in SQL.

EF translates the following

```
context.Channels
  .First(ch => ch.Channel_ID == id)
  .ChannelValues
  .Where(cv => start < cv.ValueTime && cv.ValueTime <= stop);
```

into

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Channel_ID] AS [Channel_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ChannelType_ID] AS [ChannelType_ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    FROM [dbo].[Channel] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Channel_ID] = @p__linq__0
p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Channel_ID] AS [Channel_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ValueTime] AS [ValueTime], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
    FROM [dbo].[ChannelValue] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Channel_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

The first SQL query I'm happy with, but the second should create a query similar to what the following does

```
context.ChannelValues
.Where(cv => cv.Channel_ID == id && start < cv.ValueTime && cv.ValueTime <= stop);
```

it results in

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Channel_ID] AS [Channel_ID], 
    [Extent1].[ValueTime] AS [ValueTime], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
    FROM [dbo].[ChannelValue] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Channel_ID] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__1 < [Extent1].[ValueTime]) AND ([Extent1].[ValueTime] <= @p__linq__2)
p__linq__0: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
p__linq__1: '7/1/2018 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)
p__linq__2: '7/23/2018 11:45:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false
```

Where I actually need this I don't have access to the the DatabaseContext.

Comment: Does `context.Channels.Include(ch => ch.ChannelValues).Where(ch => ch.Channel_Id = id && ch => start < ch.ChannelValue.ValueTime && ch.ChannelValue.ValueTime <= stop)` change it to the better? It's not a perfect query for the case. I just wanted to hint you to use the include.

Comment: @sprinter252 Thanks but I don't have access to the database context I only have the channel entity. I tried Include it makes the query more complex, but doesn't add the datetime where clauses

Comment: So.. What is your question?

Comment: @MennoB How do I get the date filter into the SQL query without access to database context? I'll edit my question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"I don't have access to the the DatabaseContext."_? I don't see why you're not simply using the second approach to begin with. What does the first approach give you that the second does not? Have you enabled lazy loading?

Comment: @Flater I suppose I could re-factor to pass the database context into all my functions... But that seems unnecessary when EF has all the info to begin with. As far as I understand Lazy loading is the default.

Comment: @Badger: I'm not understanding how you don't have access to the database context yet somehow still have access to EF itself. I think this is more the cause of the issue, can you elaborate on that part of the code?

Comment: If you want your query to perform some actions on your database, EF needs your DatabaseContext. You can use the same lambda's on Collections to manipulate data, but in the end there will always be something like DatabaseContext.SomeMethod() to manipulate data on the database.

Comment: @Flater So I pass the channel `context.Channels.First(ch => ch.Channel_ID == id)` on to another function, then in that function I want to access the values related to that channel `channel.ChannelValues
  .Where(cv => start < cv.ValueTime && cv.ValueTime <= stop);`

Comment: @MennoB I know the channel variable I use is placed behind a proxy object that has access to the ObjectContext (couldn't find Database context) and uses that to query the DB, but I can't access that ObjectContext without a lot of reflection.

Comment: @Badger: You really shouldn't be doing that. You're effectively still passing your context, as it is part of the "lazy loading" in the entity. However, you can't directly access your context anymore. This has many pitfalls, e.g. if your first method used a `using()` for your context, returning from the method disposes of the context even if you still haven't lazily loaded your data. You should return all the data you need **before** you close your context, and passing a lazily loaded object around from method to method is going to make your life as a developer considerably harder.

Comment: @Badger: I still don't understand why you can't just use the second option.

Comment: @Flater `using(var context = new DatabaseContext) { 
var channel = context.Channels.First(ch => ch.Channel_ID == id); 
var total = Totalize(channel);
return total;
}`

Comment: @Flater Previous comment is just an example, so I don't keep the entity around after the context is Disposed. Second option is not used because It goes a few functions deep, I could refactor, but this seems like something EF should do, otherwise navigation properties is really only useful for 1:1 up to 1:100 relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the second part of the query is getting passed to the SQL at all.

This tells SQL to return all the ChannelValues with the Channel_ID equal to id.

```
context.Channels
  .First(ch => ch.Channel_ID == id)
  .ChannelValues
```

The second where clause is then executed in memory.

```
.Where(cv => start < cv.ValueTime && cv.ValueTime <= stop);
```

To execute all of this in the database you will need to do something like this:

```
context.Channels
  .Where(ch => ch.Channel_ID == id)
  .SelectMany(x => x.ChannelValues)
  .Where(cv => start < cv.ValueTime && cv.ValueTime <= stop)
```

Though I don't know if this answers you question how to do this without access to the database context

Comment: If lazy loading is enabled, then `.ChannelValues` will not yet instantiate the data (as it has not been enumerated yet). The subsequent `.Where()` will not be an in-memory operation. If lazy loading is disabled, then it will end up with a `NullReferenceException` as `ChannelValues` is null because there was no explicit `Include`.

Comment: `SelectMany()` doesn't actually solve anything here. `First()` inherently instantiates the channel entity, no matter if you do (or don't) use `SelectMany()` afterwards.

Comment: On a test the equivalent to `.ChannelValues` was loading and not null. Have changed the `First()` to a `Where()`

Comment: But why would this be any better than OP's second suggestion? The end result is the same.

Comment: *I don't think ...* That could be stated with a bit more confidence :) What happens here is that `context.Channels.First()` pulls the `Channel` from the database, then its `ChannelValues` are loaded by lazy loading (all of them!) and finally these values are filtered, in memory. Indeed a possible solution is to use `SelectMany`.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it's the closest answer. It turns out EntityFramework lazy loading is not as 'lazy' as I'd like it to be. I might write my own extension method for First that returns my own proxy object to do what I want EF to do. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

"EF makes some very expensive queries" mmm  you have control of how you would like to use the framework with its limitation*, if you know something is bad but still do it that way its not EF fault.

You could do it exactly the way you have.

i.e. if you did this with raw sql how would you do it.

Then simply do the same in EF.

```
var channel = context.Channels.First(x=> x.Channel_ID == id)
channel.ChannelValues = context.ChannelValues.Where(x => x.Channel_ID == id 
                                             && start < x.ValueTime 
                                             && x.ValueTime <= stop
                              ).ToList();
```

Comment: The actual answer you're giving is no different from OP's second suggestion (the combined `Where` without the first). The other part (storing the subset as part of  `channel.ChannelValues`) isn't actually part of the question.

Comment: The code example provided is my second example, I however do not have access to the database context in the function that requires the values. The SQL in my question is that generated by EF.

Comment: @Badger sorry but im really confused as to what you are asking. "How do I get the date filter into the generated SQL query without access to database context?" Please just supply the sql you would like it to generate.... then we can convert that to linq

Comment: @Flater sorry I'm just trying to understand what is being asked. see reply to OP. above.